# How to add GeoJson data with mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, geojson

I am sending the object to create a user model.

```
"{ 
type: 'Point', 
coordinates: [ 25.2239771, 51.4993224 ] 
}"
```

And, here is the Mongoose Schema that I created.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const UserProfileSchema = new Schema(
  {
 
    userId: {
      type: String,
      // required: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    userFirstName: {
      type: String,
      // required: true,
    },
    userLastName: {
      type: String,
      // required: true,
    },
    userGender: {
      type: String,
      // required: true,
    },
    
    userCoordinates: {
      type: {
        type: String,
        default: 'Point',
      },
      coordinates: {
        type: [Number],
        index: '2dsphere',
      },       
    },
  },
  { collection: 'userprofilemodels' }
);

module.exports = UserProfile = mongoose.model(
  'userprofilemodels',
  UserProfileSchema
);
```

This is the code that I am using to add geoJson type file. However, I am getting an error.
I also tried to add index after the Schema has been defined

```
await new userProfileModel({
        userId,
        userFirstName,
        userLastName,
        userCoordinates,

      })
        .save()
        .then(() => {
          console.log('it worked!');
          res.send('worked!');
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log('did not worl')
          // console.log(error);
        });
```

If I exclude userCoordinates, then it works. So, def my geoJson object is wrong. However, I have no clue where I have made mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongoose supports GeoJSON objects indexing so first add the "2dsphere" index to the userCoordintes rather than to the coordinates within the object in order to make it work.

```
userCoordinates: {
      type: {
        type: String,
        default: 'Point',
      },
      coordinates: {
        type: [Number],
        default: undefined,
        required: true
      },
      index: '2dsphere'       
},
```

Make sure your userCoordinates looks something like this:

```
const userCoordinates = {
        type: "Point",
        coordinates: [coordinatesA, coordinatesB],
};
```

Comment: It looks like it works. But, only when I refresh my node, the index is applied somehow. Is there any way that I can apply this from the beginning?

Comment: This kind of indexing is applied at collection creation, this is a expected behaviour because we are not supposed to be tweaking indexes at production. It should work from now on

Answer (score 1):

Taken from the mongoose [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/geojson.html) it seems the GeoJSON Type mustn't be only a String.

here is the example with `location` as a GeoJSON type:

```js
const citySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  location: {
    type: {
      type: String, // Don't do `{ location: { type: String } }`
      enum: ['Point'], // 'location.type' must be 'Point'
      required: true
    },
    coordinates: {
      type: [Number],
      required: true
    }
  }
});
```